# Opengeo plugin does not appear in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, boundless-suite

I successfully installed the Opengeo plugin, but it doesn't appear in plugin list. 
What should i do? 
Fyi, i use QGIS 2.14 for 64 bit.

Comment: Which opengeo plugin is that you installed? and have you checked under the other menu dropdowns?

Comment: This may help you: https://connect.boundlessgeo.com/docs/desktop/latest/plugins/plugin_repo.html

Comment: After installing it, did you check the plugin check box under the installed tab?

Comment: @Knightshound I installed Boundless QGIS plugin and i already checked that dropdown, but it isn't there.

Comment: @AndreuAmoros thanks, but i already followed those steps.

Comment: @artwork21 yeah, it's all checked and the boundless opengeo repository's already conncted, but the plugin not appears

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install Boundless desktop from [connect.boundlessgeo.com](http://connect.boundlessgeo.com)
You will then log into the connect plugin from QGIS in Boundless Desktop to access the additional plugins. You can use the geoserver explorer plugin. http://blog.geoserver.org/2015/12/23/geoserver-explorer-plugin-for-qgis/